# Filter traffic by country or language

Tags: google-analytics

I am trying to create a filter in Google Analytics to fetch the relevant users for my Dutch website. The filter ought only include visitors are either reside in (`The Netherlands OR Belgium`) *or* have a language setting of `nl($|[-_])`.

That means I want to include Dutch or Belgian traffic with a different language setting, as well as international traffic with a Dutch setting and exclude everyone else.

I'm trying to add geographic data to the custom-advanced filter, but the option is not here, so I cannot construct the Constructor.

How do I create this filter?

Answer (score 0):

<s>As far as I can tell view filters work on the raw request data, so you cannot have geo information (since this is computed from the IP, not sent along with the request).</s> (So that part was bullsh* as pointed out in the comment, but the rest of the anwser is still viable).

So you can either send geo data along as a custom dimension (in Universal Analytics) which will obviously not work for historical data (plus will require some programming effort on your part).

So I would suggest that you use [segmentation](http://analytics.blogspot.de/2013/07/re-imagining-segmentation-in-analytics.html) instead - segments work on processed data so you can use geo information.

Plus I think this question should be migrated to webmasters.stackoverflow.com since it is not actually about programming.

Comment: While your description makes perfect sense, the include and exclude options of custom filters do have a `country` option. I can't use it because the options `country` and `language` need to be in one filter. I'm forces to use the advance filter but that doesn't have the `country` option.